# Pivot table grouping by week - can't get it to start on Monday

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

In Excel 2016, I'm trying to set up a pivot table which has a Date-format column and group it by weeks.

Ungrouped, the data looks like this:

[image: ungrouped]

I'm then trying to group it using the following settings:

[image: grouping settings]

The data then appears like this:

[image: grouped]

As you can see, the grouping starts on 6th Sep 2017 which was a Wednesday. Presumably this is because where my data starts.

Unfortunately, this renders the data somewhat useless. I need the data grouped by weeks starting on a Monday.

I've tried changing the Starting With and Ending With settings to:

- The Monday before 06 Sep
- The Monday after 06 Sep
- The Sunday after 23 Jan
- The Monday after 23 Jan
- The Monday before 23 Jan
- The Sunday before 23 Jan

Regardless of what I try, I can't get the weeks to group starting on a Monday.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: #Dunc, Check I've solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since you have tried all these,,*

**I've tried changing the Starting With and Ending With settings to:**

The Monday before 06 Sep

The Monday after 06 Sep

The Sunday after 23 Jan

The Monday after 23 Jan

The Monday before 23 Jan

The Sunday before 23 Jan

**Now my suggestion is,**

**While Grouping, either you set the Start Date as 04/09/2017 or 02/01/2017 and "Un-Check the Start Date Checkbox and Click OK".**

**Check the Screen Shot I've tested your Data & Group on Date by using 02-01-2017 as Start Date, it's Working, now the Start Date after Group is 04-09-2017 is the Monday.**

[image]

*Hope this help you.*